# Grails foreign key input

Tags: grails, gsp

I have a simple domain class with a foreign key

```
class A
{
  Integer Id
  String name
  ...
}

class B
{
 Integer Id
 A a
}
```

I need to write a form for B, where the user just inputs the name. 
Right now I'm doing this by reading the params in save and setting the values explicitly `bInstance.a = A.findByName(formParams.name)`

Is there a cleaner way to do this?

Comment: You don't need to add the `id` attribute to your class, Grails already do that :-)

Comment: Regarding your question, the cleaner version would be params.a.id.

Comment: @SérgioMichels The user inputs a name of string type in the form, I need to get the Id for that string and set it to B, how does params.a.id do it?

Comment: I think that your question was "It's a cleaner way to send the relation to the controller"? But if it is regarding the name, findByName is fine...